# how to input the model into the KNN classification algorithm?

Tags: python, opencv, knn

I want to make image clasification using KNN. i use https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-custom-data-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/ to make a model. i have 20 image which 10 image in dog category and 10 image in  cat category. I'm having trouble entering the model into the KNN algorithm,there is a problem in my coding. this is my code:

```
knn_model=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3) #define K=3
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
predict_knn=knn_model.predict(X_test)
print(predict_knn)
```

there is an error : found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [60, 20]

I need your opinion how to fix this code. thank you.

Comment: The error may be caused by the different lengths of `X` and `Y`. Could you provide the dimensions of each tensor? (`x_train.shape`, ...)

Comment: please post a minimal working example (`NameError: name 'KNeighborsClassifier' is not defined`)

Comment: @JihoChoi x_train.shape is (20, 32, 32, 1), but y is a list and get error to print shape

Comment: @RiandraPutra, what's the size (len()) of the list `y`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be due to the **inconsistent sample size** of `X` and `y`.

###### 1. `len(y) == 20`

```
# Works
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = np.arange(20*32*32*3).reshape((20, 32, 32, 3)), list(range(20))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
```

###### 2. `len(y) == 60`

```
# Does not work
X, y = np.arange(20*32*32*3).reshape((20, 32, 32, 3)), list(range(60))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
```

The second script produces the below error.

[image]

Comment: that's still have problem error : Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.